Does an automation with various sql activities, on automation studio, still writes on the target Data Extension if the activity gets an error?
What apparently is happening is that my activity on step 3 still writes some records on the target Data extension, despite getting an error (Cannot insert null values). The error is simple and is resolved, but what I am seeing is that some records wore still written on the data extension, despite getting an error for several days. Has this happened to anyone?
